# Java LinkedList sort changed the other list

Tags: java, sorting, median

I want to sort a list of numbers without change the original list. So this is what I did:

```
public double median(){
    //first,sort the list
    LinkedList<Double>sorted = entries;
    Collections.sort(sorted); ...
```

entries is another LinkedList that I would like to have it unsorted.
I created a new LinkedList named sorted for not changing the original  entries list. The sorted list is only used for this double function.
However everytime when I call the function it still sorts the entries list.

### How can I sort it without changing the original list?

What I've done so far:

1. LinkedListsorted = entries;

2.

```
LinkedList<Double>sorted = new LinkedList<Double>();
Collections.copy(sorted,entries);
```

3.

```
LinkedList<Double>sorted = new LinkedList<Double>();
for(int i=0;i<entries.size();i++){
sorted.add(entries.get(i));}
```

And none of them are working properly.
They do the sort work, but they changed the entries list which I don't want to change.

---

Thanks everyone.
The problem is now solved. I copy pasted them to another software and paste back and it now works properly.
I still can't understand why though.

Comment: _I created a new LinkedList_ <-- No, you didn't.  You created another reference to the same list.

Comment: Do `LinkedList<Double> sorted = new LinkedList<>(entries);`. To understand the underlying cause of the behavior you see, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 2):

You haven't created a new list, you have just assigned it to variable called `sorted`, if want to have a sorted copy then you would need to copy it to another list as follows.

```
LinkedList<Double> sorted = new LinkedList<Double>();
Collections.copy(sorted, entries);
Collections.sort(sorted);
```

Comment: I had tried to build it using new. And add elements to it. But not working.

Comment: It sorts both lists. I tried using Collections.copy and new Linkedlist with for loop and add, but they sorts both sorted and entries.

Comment: could you please show how  you do that? I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 1):

```
public static LinkedList<Double> sort(LinkedList<Double> list) {
    LinkedList<Double> res = new LinkedList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is usecase?